# Nested div tag widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested

If I have a container div, with 3 `div`s within that `div`. And each of those 3 `div`s have a width of 33%.  They fit perfectly inline.

If i add a 1 px border to the 3 divs it throws them off and are no longer in line and pushes the 3rd `div` under the other two.

How do i keep the 3 `div`s perfectly over the container, while still using a border to show the 3 `div`s specifically.

Here is the JS fiddle example, please see the `div`s with the "1" that I am having trouble with.

https://jsfiddle.net/p0yzrL0j/

Second question:

How can i keep the sizes fixed? so that any time the window is resized the divs shrink to match the window size rather than moving under each other.

Comment: Always put a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example with

```
box-sizing: borderbox;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8c644nhv/1/

You can increase the border size and it will not add to the div width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

That includes any border and padding that the boxes could have with the total width and height. [W3C Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Grid systems usually have this applied using universal selectors.

```
*,after,before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you don't want to use "box-sizing: border-box;"

Use calc().

Since your boxes have 1px border. That adds 1px to the left and 1px to the right. So you have to minus 2px from the 33% width.

```
#stats {
    width: calc(33% - 2px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I Just Used widths using calc for one div for subtraction of border widths from total with of divs now it can automatically adjusts for any resolution**

```css
.one{
 width:33%;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid red;
 float:left;
}
.two{
 width:-webkit-calc(34% - 7px);
 width:-moz-calc(34% - 7px);
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid blue;
 float:left;
}
I Just Used widths using calc for one div for subtraction of border widths from total with of divs now it can automatically adjusts for any resolution
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="one">3</div>
```